# Bootstrap Daterangepicker styling doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

I'm using customed bootstrap daterangepicker from website http://www.daterangepicker.com/ .
So I have next question: If I add 2 files: daterangepicker.js and daterangepicker.css from hyperlink in the example to my webpage everything works perfect. But, when I create this 2 files in my project and copy/paste code there, then add  as {% static 'css/daterangepicker.css' %} (same to js) - Js file works fine, but css file collapse all my bootstrap css styling and calendar styling too.

I'm really stucked.

Platform I'm using is django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The Problem was, that I created new file in the same folder as bootstrap files, not in plugins. Create new file in plugins/folder/daterangepicker.css